# electric bedroom heated mattress vs danger

Tags: security

We have one 220v electric bedroom heated mattress which repaired by ordinary repairman and changed its board, the circuit is this kind:

[image]

[image]

And the burned spot in the Blanket:

[image]

Its used some resistor and one TRIAC IC ( [BT139 600E](https://datasheetspdf.com/mobile-pdf/1135255/EASTSEMICONDUCTOR/BT139-600/1)), so in new circuit there is no damage on it, and the new circuit worked for almost one week usage!

**Update:**

I have seen some heater blanket circuit like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=heater%20blanket%20%20circuit&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiq77j955npAhVO16QKHaGiAYcQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=heater%20blanket%20%20circuit&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1DQ9Q5Y0PUOYOb2DmgAcAB4AIABAIgBAJIBAJgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1n&sclient=img&ei=P9WvXurTNs6ukwWhxYa4CA&bih=949&biw=1853):

[image]

and seen in the failed circuit there is **no bridge diode**, also it is strange for me to use **non isolated power supply** in the **original** circuit of our blanket( dose it standard?!!!), and bypassed the bridge diodes like this kind:

[image]

And thought dose it could be the failure reason and how the heater elements could work with **0 -220v** voltage ?!

So why this happened?

Thanks.

Comment: it is the Blanket

Comment: are you saying that the heated mattress burned a hole in the blanket?

Comment: yes that happened

Comment: you will have to call a qualified technician to examine the mattress if you want to determine what happened ... you are going to get only pointless guesses on the internet

Comment: It looks dangerous. Don't let that repairman near your electrical devices ever again.

Comment: I think "repaired" is rather optimistic.  Given how many tracks have been cut on the circuit board, most of the original functions won't be there any more.  It probably overheated because there was nothing to turn it off.

Comment: i looked at the pictures using my PC and i take back what i said in my previous comment (my phone has a flaky display and i did not see the pictures clearly) ... no need for a qualified technician .... the repairman butchered the control unit ... it may even be possible that the repairman is trying to do you harm

Comment: 1. The repairman did not know what he is doing. 2. This blanket could kill you or burn your home 3. While it is sad to have to buy another one, you are risking your life by continuing to use this blanket or this controller. Very sadly, both should be destroyed and discarded. 4. While the repairer may have genuinely been trying to help they lack the knowledge or the repair skills to do an adequate or safe job. 5. The "controller" has probably applied to much energy and allowed the blanket to overheat.

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming that the heating device is an "electric blanket" used on top of a mattress.
Such blankets MUST NOT be used underneath a mattress as they can then cause fires.
If this is NOT an electric blanket, please advise.

The "controller" has applied too much energy and allowed the blanket to overheat. The "repairs" are poorly done, the blanket is dangerously damaged and the controller is not reasonably able to be repaired.

1. The repairman is not a competent repairer.
2. This blanket could kill you or burn your home
3. While it is sad to have to buy another blanket, you are risking your life by continuing to use this blanket or this controller. Very sadly, both should be destroyed and discarded.
4. While the repairer may have genuinely been trying to help they lack the knowledge or the repair skills to do an adequate or safe
   job.

---

I admire your enthusiasm for attempting to deal with this circuit. Without great effort attempting to see what the 'repairer' has done it's completely unknown what the finished circuit is or whether it in fact "controls" the heating level at all. I do not know with certainty what the diodes did or what the circuit now does.

It is usual for electric blankets to NOT have a power supply that is isolated from the mains. The whole of the wiring should be considered to always be at mains voltage when plugged in. Depending on the design the wiring may be "live" when plugged in but not operating!.

Note that "isolated" usually means using a transformer with electrically separated primary and secondary windings. Use of diodes alone does not provide isolation.

Comment: Thanks @Russell_McMahon, could you say you opinion too, about the none isolated power supply and also bypassing it ... ( Update part of question.)

Comment: @xinani7057_tgres24.com See addition to my answer. For interest, where are you located. What is the approximate cost of a replacement heating device (blanket? mattress?) || Was it on the top layer above the mattress when it overheated? Using a heating element UNDER a mattress can cause problems like this.

Comment: Iran, its cost is not too much for us by don't changed it and repaired it, and it was above of my elderly mother ( brain stoke problem ...)